# Finding previous value of radio button when I select other option of radio button in Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I have a problem using knockout js .Here I am using observable array where property name selectedItem bind with radiobutton checked attribute.When I am changing any option I want both previous value and present value which is clicked.

```
<div style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.28; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 10px;"
      data-bind="foreach:OptionDetail">
  <div>
    **<input  type="radio" class="mts" style="float: left; margin-left: 5px" data-bind="attr:{name:ParentCourseItemID,value:OptionDescription},click:function($root,event){SaveOptionForPoll($root,Option,SelectedItemID)},checked:SelectedItemID" />**
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" data-bind="attr:{id:'hdnSelectOption'+CourseItemID}" />
  <div data-bind="event: { mouseover: $root.ShowVoteCount, mouseout: $root.HideVoteCount }" style="margin-bottom: 5px; border: 1px solid #CCC; background-color: white;
                                zoom: 1; float: left; width: 210px; margin-left: 5px; height: 25px;">
    <div style="text-align: left; float: left; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 5px;" data-bind="html:OptionDescription">
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; display:none; width: 50px; background-color: yellow; height: 52%; padding: 6px;"
        data-bind="attr:{id:'poll'+CourseItemID}">
      <span style="margin-right:5px;" data-bind="text:VoteCount"></span>Votes
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; height: 100%">
    <span style="position: relative; top: 4px"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about showing us some code?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just record the previous value each time the current value changes. Something like.

```
var viewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    this.value = ko.observable();
    this.previousValue = ko.observable(this.value());

    this.value.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        console.log("current value: " + newValue + " previousValue: " 
               + self.previousValue());
        // do something with previous value
        self.previousValue(self.value());    
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/2ZwDm/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for give me link it is perfectly work for observable variable.But I am using observable array.So how to find particular previous value of radio button of particular object in list.

Comment: @user1242675 - I don't quite understand? Can you show your js code. I'm sure this solution can be applied.